# Delete a sub folder with specific name from all sub folders?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

I know how to delete a single sub folder or multiple ones by mask:

> rmdir /s /q C:\Somedir\DirToDelete

or

> rmdir /s /q C:\Somedir\DirsToDelete*

But I want to delete all sub folders, say, with name DeleteMe, from all sub folders within C:\Somedir.

Ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you want to list all the directories you want to remove. Then use that to delete them all. Here's a quick and dirty example using what you put in there.

```
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`"dir C:\Somedir /ad/b/s DirsToDelete"`) do rmdir "%%a"
```

Please test this out before you kick it off for your environment. I usually would replace the rmdir with echo to make sure it works.

Comment: `rmdir` will only remove empty directories so in some cases `rmdir /s /q "%%a"` might be more appropriate.

Comment: %%a is for Batch file, use %a for a command-line. For me, the working solution is (including support for space in directory name): ```for /f "usebackq delims=^=^" %a in (`"dir DirsToDelete /ad/b/s"`) do rmdir /s /q "%a"```

Answer (score 9):

Another way is (only PowerShell)

```
 Remove-Item -path e:\path\*\path\*\* -Filter *DeleteMe* -WhatIf
```

Remove all *DeleteMe* dirs recursive in last "asterisk" path.

-WhatIf = only show which dirs will remove, no do it - nice for check before destroy other data:)

**UPDATE 1** 
After some labor... this update is better... line before can delete only empty folders. This can delete folder with content:

```
get-childitem -path E:\path\*\path\*\* -recurse -filter *DeleteMe* | remove-item -whatif -force -recurse
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP wanted cmd/batch compatible commands... You should at least mention that this is PowerShell.

Comment: True, notice added

Comment: +1, and the OP should mention he wanted to use a batch script, as Powershell definitely counts as Windows command line nowadays.

Comment: I had to add '-recurse' in order to get this to work like so: `get-childitem `<strong> -recurse </strong>` -path C:\dev\* -filter target | remove-item -whatif -force -recurse`

Comment: +1 I like the way it doesn't have double quotes so I can put the folder name in double quotes for folders with spaces in the name, also the fact that I could remove (for example) `cover` and `covers` folders with `cover*` is nice.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a bat file, update and paste below code

> FOR /d /r . %%d IN ("Your folder name to be deleted") DO @IF EXIST "%%d" rd /s /q
>   "%%d"

2. Copy this bat file to your parent folder (could be C: or D: too)
3. Run it